# How to get all the parameters passed to the request in web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

I am trying to get all the parameters passed to the request so that I can validate if any parameter which is not declared in the class file will throw an exception.

Suppose my class file is:

```
    [PermissionFilter("somepermision")]
    [Route("/Userdetails", "POST")]
    public class UserDetails
    {
        public string surname{ get; set; }
        public string forename{ get; set; }
    }
```

So if the user sends parameters wrongly from Postman I want to throw an exception. is there any way to get all the request parameters from the end user. So that I can validate it according to my requirement. Suppose user sends some extra parameters along with the mention parameters in the request class file I want to throw an exception in that case.

Comment: you need to configure your routes and will not hit unnecessary your api

Comment: It is very unusual to care about *additional* parameters that are not needed. Do you really need to do this at all? Those details will just get ignored anyway.

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is if the end user sends parameter sur name instead of surname by mistake then I want to send an error message to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the Request Parameters in Request.Parameters in MS_QueryNameValuePairs key

```
 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        var keyValuePair =this.Request.Properties["MS_QueryNameValuePairs"];
    }
```

and Make a foor loop on it to fetch them or you can take them manualy like this:

```
      [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        var query = this.Request.RequestUri.Query;
        query.Remove(0);
        List<string> paramteters = query.Split('&').ToList();
     }
```

this will work for you :D